# Is there a renaming-safe way to check if a provided key string represents X in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, key, rename, type-safety

- I have a `User` object, which has some attributes such `phone`.
- I also have a function like this: `delete(userId: string, userAttr: keyof User)`

The function is intended to set `NULL` in the database a given attribute for a specific user. If trying to delete the user's phone, there is extra logic that must be run.

What common sense tells me is that I can just write something like `if (userAttr === 'phone')`, but, what happens if in the future we do a renaming of the `User` object attributes, and `phone` is changed to something like `phoneNumber`? This `if` statement will be useless and its body will never be executed.

Therefore, is there a renaming-safe way to check if a provided `keyof User string` is the one that indicates the user's phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This already works exactly as you want it to:

```
type User = { name: string, phone: string }
function delete(userId: string, userAttr: keyof User) {
  if (userAttr === 'phone') return 123;
  else return 456;
}
```

then later, [we change the name of the attribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3lAdgQwLYQBcUcwiAllgOYA02ArngEZLGkXVQC+AsAFAAzelgDGwcgHssUACYQANhGAQAKgAp6CRAEkZbMpVpRNSAILAyxANYQQEgbC0BKDPyhRyDjVvNlUKNAByMAALKQhAl0QlekRpAEYAJgBmAG43KAUEKGjgWOkAFgBWADZ0vi4gA) from `phone` to `phoneNumber` then TypeScript will tell us:

> This condition will always return `false` since the types `"phoneNumber" | "name"` and `"phone"` have no overlap.(2367)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was looking for something so complicated that I didn't fall into the obvious. That's a good example of the Occam's razor. It's safe enough as it should break the tests if the `if` statement remains unchanged. Thanks!